# Bug in Scala's type system?

Tags: scala

The following scala code seems to be valid:

```
class A[X]
class C[M[X] <: A[X]]

class Main

new C[A]
```

I expected the compiler to perform type inference on type A, but after I tried the following:

```
new C[A[Int]]
```

I got the following error message:

```
(fragment of Main.scala):11: error: this.A[Int] takes no type parameters, expected: one
println( new C[A[Int]] )
```

Answer (score 15):

Let's see what this means in plain English.

```
class A[X]
```

means: let A be a class that takes one type parameter.

```
class C[M[X] <: A[X]]
```

means: let C be a class that takes one type parameter, which should be a class that takes one type parameter AND, parameterized, is a subclass of class A parameterized with the same type.

When you write

```
new C[A]
```

you're saying: create an instance of C with A as parameter. Does A conform to the criteria above? Yes, it's a class that takes one type parameter, and parameterized it is a subclass of itself parameterized.

However, when you write

```
new C[A[Int]]
```

the type parameter you're trying to give C, A[Int], does not conform to the criteria: A[Int] does not take any type parameters, which the compiler kindly tells you. (And it is not a subclass of A[X] either.)

Comment: This is the correct answer; the only thing that I would add (to aid in web searches) is that this is an example of a higher-kinded type, where the type parameter to C is referred to as having kind * -> *. A[Int] by contrast simply has kind *.

Comment: Did you mean `A` instead of `C`? `A[Int]` has the kind `*`, but A should be  `* -> *`, no? Then `C` should be `(* -> *) -> *`?

Answer (score 6):

Try this syntax.

```
class C[M <: A[_]]
```

This means that C is a class that takes one type parameter, which should be a subclass of A and takes one type parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't declare `X` as a type parameter for `C`. Try the following:

```
class C[X, M[X] <: A[X]]
```

Comment: this won't do the job either. The problem is that C expects a type with a type parameter. When you try new C[A] this is going to work, because A takes a type argument.

Answer (score 0):

You don't wan't your class to take ONE type parameter, you wan't it to take two! Two possible solutions:

```
class A[X] {
     type T = X
}
class C[M <: A[_]] {
     //use M#T if you want the type T was parameterized with.
}
```

Or, you can do:

```
class A[X]
class C[T, M[A] <: A[A]] {
     //when you want the type, write M[T], not M.
}
```

HOWEVER, what you probably want is this:

```
class A[X]
class C[M <: A[_]]
```

Comment: To make it easier, this is the equivalent in java:
class A<X> {...} //for all.
class C<M extends A<?>> {...} //first. not perfect though.
//second is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's all explained [here](http://adriaanm.github.io/research/2010/10/06/new-in-scala-2.8-type-constructor-inference/), focus on the "Common Pitfalls" section because it is quite TLTR.